# react native - arrow notation

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
<TouchableHighlight
  onPressIn={this._onPressIn}
>

_onPressIn = () => {
  this.setState({ pressing: true });
}
//1. works

_onPressIn(){
  this.setState({ pressing: true });
}
//2. error
```

---

```
<TouchableHighlight
  onPress={this._onPress}
>

_onPress(){
  Alert.alert('','HELLO');
}
//3. works

_onPress=()=>{
  Alert.alert('','HELLO');
}
//4. works
```

I can't speak English very well. So I'm not sure if you will get what I say, but I will try hard to make you understand my words.

Are there something difference between 1 and 2 ??
If it exist, then why 3 and 4 have same result??

I have thought there's no difference between 1 and 2.. But example 1 is working normally, the other is not..

Comment: arrow function sets the this context automatically, however you would generally set the arrow function inside the jsx code, or you would bind the function with this in the constructor

Comment: the difference is the `this` keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are not using an arrow function you have to bind "this" to your Button. e.g:

```
<TouchableHighlight
  onPressIn={this._onPressIn.bind(this)}
>
```

should work for case #2.

Comment: @조광수 you're welcome. Could you please mark the question as correct? (beside my answer click on the check icon) Thank you

Comment: In case 3, though I didn't bind 'this',  why it works normally?

Comment: @조광수 in case #3 you don't use 'this' in your function, therefore ýou don't have to bind 'this' to your current context.